# Passing a pointer to a function?

Tags: c, prototype, function-pointers

I want to achieve this code:

```
state(state);
```

So, first I declare a pointer to a function. I set the pointer to the `start` function. And the `start` function takes a pointer to a function also. I call the function using the `state` pointer, and pass the `state` pointer along for modification in `start`.

How do I properly declare the function pointer created in `main`, and how do I declare the prototypes?

Comment: Try to write what you do in pseudocode, otherwise it is difficult to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intention isn't very clear but you can pass function pointers like this:

```
int g ((*myfunc)(int x))
{
 stuff for g;
 (*myfunc)(2);
}

int f (int a)
{
 stuff for f;
}

main()
{
 g (f);
}
```

Comment: `(*myfunc)(2);` may be written as `myfunc(2);`. Function calls actually use pointers to functions, not functions. When a call is written directly to a function, like `sqrt(x)`, the function is automatically converted to a pointer, as if `(&sqrt)(x)` had been written. When you already have a pointer, there is no need to dereference it. If you do, the compiler automatically undoes the dereferencing.